# Select top 2 sales in each class SQL

Tags: sql, greatest-n-per-group

[image]

I have the table which I want select only top 2 sales in each class, the result is

```
Sophia   A 40
Jennifer A 15
Greg     B 50
Jeff     B 20
Stella   B 20
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

window function dense_rank also fulfil expected result condition of sample data

```
 select * from
    (select * , dense_rank() over(partition by class order by scores DESC ) as rn 
     from tablea
     ) t where rn<=2
```

Comment: @KEVINBOSS https://stackoverflow.com/help/accepted-answer                     there is a option accept answer click on that answer will be accept

Comment: cool in this case dense_rank is better than rank () thank you :)

Answer (score 4):

You could use `RANK`:

```
SELECT *
FROM (SELECT *, RANK() OVER(PARTITION BY class ORDER BY sales DESC) AS rnk
      FROM tab) sub
WHERE rnk <=2;
```

Comment: Yaa, it works but Stella and Jeff  are same at sales only one shows up

Comment: @KEVINBOSS Please check again. RANK() will give the same value for tie.

Comment: I just checked again and I only got 4 rows as it should be 5